# Android Studio is re installing APK every time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After I updated my android studio and gradle, It is installing apk everytime even I put new empty line or log only in java.

I used to be not like this. It just updated the apk and relaunch the activity.

Android studio 2.3.1, gradle: 2.3.1

Is there any option or setting I have to set?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some cases *instant run* doesn't work like when you use the jack compiler (we won't be using it soon and Java 8 will be officially supported!).

Another reason is when you try to run the app on an emulator with a software version that is not installed on your computer such as having platform version 24 and running on a 25 version emulator.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for answer. This helped me to understand the issue. But I cannot solve it. should I just wait for Java 8?

Comment: in case you're using the jack compiler then yes. And you're welcome!